# Corona SDK: parsing JSON

Tags: json, coronasdk

I have a JSON string which I can parse with Corona SDK.
What I could not figure out yet is how to use the return value and assign it to a variable which I can access later?

I get the JSON string in this function:

```
    local function networkListener( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
                print( "Network error!")
        else            
                print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
        end
end
```

The return value looks like this:

```
[{"id":"25761","name":"Legend Of Zelda: Ocarina Of Time 3D, The","cnt":"15"},{"id":"26106","name":"Zelda No Densetsu: Toki No Ocarina 3D","cnt":"15"}]
```

How can I make a table from that return value? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require "json"

local t = json.decode( jsonFile( "sample.json" ) )
```

[Exploring JSON Usage in Corona](http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/08/tutorial-exploring-json-usage-in-corona/)